# Inserting item in TreeView

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I created two panes in a splitter window, one pane for tree view and another is for list view.
After creating these panes in splitter window, I am not getting how to add items to treeview and listview.

CXTreeView is derived from CTreeView and CXListView is derived from CListView. 
CXTreeView is used for created left pane that is tree and CXTreeView is used for creating right pane that is list.

I created like this:

```
int CTreeWnd:: OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if(CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;


    m_oSplitterWnd = DEBUG_NEW CXSplitterWnd;
    if(!m_oSplitterWnd.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create splitter\n");
        return -1;
    }

    m_oSplitterWnd.SetLeftRTPane(RUNTIME_CLASS (CXTreeView));
    m_oSplitterWnd.SetRightRTPane(RUNTIME_CLASS (CXListView));

    if(!m_oSplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 0, m_oSplitterWnd.GetLeftRTPane(), CSize(250, 100), NULL)||
    !m_oSplitterWnd.CreateView(0, 1, m_oSplitterWnd.GetRightRTPane(), CSize(100, 100), NULL))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create views in splitter\n");
    return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CSplitterWnd::GetPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ffbc6de.aspx) to retrieve a pointer to each Pane, they will be pointers to your `CXTreeView` and `CXListView` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get your views from the splitter, which you can do like this:

```
CXTreeView *pTreeView = (CXTreeView*)m_oSplitterWnd.GetPane(0, 0);
CXListView *pListView = (CXListView*)m_oSplitterWnd.GetPane(0, 1);
```

Then, from those views, access the underlying tree control and list control:

```
CTreeCtrl &pTreeCtrl = pTreeView->GetTreeCtrl();
CListCtrl &pListCtrl = pListView->GetListCtrl();
```

Now, you can use the functions exposed by [CTreeCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bkz91b4.aspx) and [CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) to change the content of the tree and the list respectively, for example by using [CTreeCtrl::InsertItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ettyybhw.aspx) and [CListCtrl::InsertItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9s12fc.aspx) to add new items:

```
pTreeCtrl.InsertItem( /* ... whatever ... */ );
pListCtrl.InsertItem( /* ... whatever ... */ );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roger Rowland.